# How to set default value to map value when doing json Unmarshal in golang?

Tags: json, go

I have a struct like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type request struct {
    Version    string               `json:"version"`
    Operations map[string]operation `json:"operations"`
}
type operation struct {
    Type   string `json:"type"`
    Width  int    `json:"width"`
    Height int    `json:"height"`
}

func main() {
    jsonStr := "{\"version\": \"1.0\", \"operations\": {\"0\": {\"type\": \"type1\", \"width\": 100}, \"1\": {\"type\": \"type2\", \"height\": 200}}}"
    req := request{
         Version: "1.0",
    }
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println(req)
    }
}
```

I can set Version = "1.0" as its default value, but how can I set default value to Width and Height?

Comment: Your `json` doesn't appear to be valid, `Unmarshal` returns an err, so throw an `err := ` in front of that `Unmarshal` and I'm sure you'll be able to debug it yourself, but for now I don't really understand your question, you're using a `float` in place of an `int32` and your `json` doesn't appear to be valid.

Comment: THANK YOU. I modified my code, it can compile and run now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write an unmarshal function to set the default values:

```
func (o *operation) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    type xoperation operation
    xo := &xoperation{Width: 500, Height: 500}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, xo); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *o = operation(*xo)
    return nil
}
```

I created a [playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/L232knrhi2) with modifications to the JSON to make it runnable.